# Updating an existing Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I already created a free app using Eclipse and have it on Google Play. Now I am wanting to add some extra features into it and have it as a paid app. Now I am wondering if I have to create a whole new program or will changing the existing package name and export key suffice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play does not allow you to change a free app to a paid app. The reasons behind it are beyond me. You have to upload a new app with a new package name onto Google Play. In eclipse right click on the project and select "Android Tools -> Rename Application Package". You don't have to create a new keystore to export the app, you can use the same you used for the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to update your app, you can add your new features. Without changing the `package` declaration or creating a new application

If you `sign` the apk with a different `keystore`, your app won't be updated in `Play Store`, instead of that, It will re-install the app and your users will lose the saved data.